# FOUC (Flash of unstyled content) since less.js

Tags: javascript, html, less, fouc

I started to use `Less.js` in my project but since I packed all my style in a .less file, I'm getting very bad FOUC. Anyone knows what to do against that?

Comment: compile the less to css, rather than letting the lib render it after domcontentloaded etc, it says in the docs *Using Less.js in the browser is the easiest way to get started and convenient for developing with Less, but in production, when performance and reliability is important, we recommend pre-compiling using Node.js or one of the many third party tools available.*

Comment: Alright i'm going to look into that thank you very much. Can you put your comment into a answer so i can mark it as done later? :)